# System.Data.Sqlite BLOBs without bufferring entire sequence into RAM

Tags: sqlite, streaming, system.data.sqlite

I want to know if there's a way to read/write a BLOB column using System.Data.Sqlite without having to have the entire binary sequence in memory after reading and before writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This feature](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/32d482b38b) has not been implemented.

Comment: Seems to have been implemented now.